# While Loop Stopping

Tags: python

The Code is working, but after 2 trys of the code it will just stop, this is in the section of playagain() when im asking the yes or no question it will display the error but will stop after the trys am i doing it wrong?

```
import random
import time
import getpass
import sys

def game1():
    number = (input("Please Enter Your 3 Digit Code e.g.(0 0 1): "))
    if number.isnumeric(): #if its a number
        counter = 0
        x = True
        L = 1
        H = 100
        while x == True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            randomguess = random.randint(L,H)
            print("%03d"%randomguess)
            if randomguess > int(number):
                print("The Passcode is lower")
                H = randomguess
            elif randomguess < int(number):
                print("The Passcode is higher")
                L = randomguess
            else:
                print("The Passcode is Equal")
                x = False
            counter = counter + 1
            if randomguess == int(number):
                print("Well Done the Prisoner has Escaped, he did it in",counter,"trys")
                return playagain()

            if counter > 9:
                print("The Prisoner get it wrong",counter,"times he is locked in, Well Done Jailer")
                return playagain()

    else:
        print("This is Invalid, Please Provide a 3 Digit Code")
#This is the Section just for Reference
def playagain():
    playagain = input("Do you wish to play again (yes/no): ")
    if playagain == "yes":
        print("You chose to play again")
        return game1()
    elif playagain == "no":
        print("So you let the prisoner escape, thats it your fired")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Thanks for Playing")
        time.sleep(2)
        #quit("Thanks for Playing") #quit game at this point
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Please choose a valid option")
        return
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cleaned-up version:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

DELAY = 0.5

def get_int(prompt, lo=None, hi=None):
    while True:
        try:
            val = int(input(prompt))
            if (lo is None or lo <= val) and (hi is None or val <= hi):
                return val
        except ValueError:
            # not an int, try again
            pass

def get_yn(prompt):
    while True:
        yn = input(prompt).strip().lower()
        if yn in {"y", "yes"}:
            return True
        elif yn in {"n", "no"}:
            return False

def game(tries=100):
    code = get_int("Please enter a 3-digit number (ie 091): ", 0, 999)
    lo, hi = 0, 999
    for attempt in range(1, tries+1):
        sleep(DELAY)
        guess = randint(lo, hi)
        if guess < code:
            print("Guessed {:03d} (too low!)".format(guess))
            lo = guess + 1
        elif guess > code:
            print("Guessed {:03d} (too high!)".format(guess))
            hi = guess - 1
        else:
            print("{:03d} was correct! The prisoner escaped on attempt {}.".format(guess, attempt))
            return True
    print("The prisoner failed to escape!")
    return False

def main():
    while True:
        game()
        if get_yn("Do you want to play again? "):
            print("You chose to play again.")
        else:
            print("Alright, bye!")
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Im a beginner programmer right now so it will be difficult to understand

Comment: I now understand this its so clever

Answer (score 0):

```
def game1():        
    number = (input("Please Enter Your 3 Digit Code e.g.(0 0 1): "))
    if number.isnumeric(): #if its a number
        counter = 0
        x = True
        L = 1
        H = 100
        while x == True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            randomguess = random.randint(L,H)
            print("%03d"%randomguess)
            if randomguess > int(number):
                print("The Passcode is lower")
                H = randomguess
            elif randomguess < int(number):
                print("The Passcode is higher")
                L = randomguess
            else:
                print("The Passcode is Equal")
                x = False
            counter = counter + 1
            if randomguess == int(number):
                print("Well Done the Prisoner has Escaped, he did it in",counter,"trys")
                x = False

            if counter > 9:
                print("The Prisoner get it wrong",counter,"times he is locked in, Well Done Jailer")
                x = False
    else:
        print("This is Invalid, Please Provide a 3 Digit Code")

    playagain()

#This is the Section just for Reference
def playagain():
    playagain = ""
    while (playagain != "yes" or playagain != "no"):
       playagain = input("Do you wish to play again (yes/no): ")
       if playagain == "yes":
           print("You chose to play again")
           return game1()
       elif playagain == "no":
           print("So you let the prisoner escape, thats it your fired")
           time.sleep(2)
           print("Thanks for Playing")
           time.sleep(2)
           #quit("Thanks for Playing") #quit game at this point
           sys.exit()
       else:
           print("Please choose a valid option")

game1()
```

See https://repl.it/B7uf/3 for a working example.

Games typically run in a game loop which you have implemented using `while x = True`.  The gameloops exits when the game is over and then user is asked to restart it.  The bugs you were experiencing were due to the gameloop prematurely exiting before the user could be asked to restart.

The code below above that problem.  There are other things that could be updated to improve the flow, but will leave that to you.

- Use try/catch blocks instead of boolean checks
- Break the game loop out into a separate method

Comment: Be aware, this recursively stacks up calls; if you replay the game 100 times it will crash your program. Better to rewrite it with a while loop.

Comment: Thanks but when I did this it showed up with this error it gave me a str is not callable error

Comment: You're right, fixing the code now.  The point is you're ending the game on when an invalid entry is entered instead of restarting the playagain request.  One second..

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear but what i wanted it to do after print is start the function over again, but im not sure how to

Comment: Not sure I completely understand.  Could you reword?

Comment: Doesnt matter i asked a stupid question i had to reread the code you gave me to make sense of it